# get_template_part isn't working and I have the correct file path

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a WordPress theme and I'm having a problem with the `get_template_part` function. I'm using it to call on a file that has the content within a WP loop (content, tags, author, etc.) for a custom post type, but I'm also having the problem with the regular posts. 
This is what the code looks like:
`<?php get_template_part('includes/section','blogcontent');?><?php wp_link_pages();?>`
my file structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgt1O.png)
When I load the page that its on, I can see the everything else on the page file (single-cars.php) including the navigation bar at the top. Also the `wp_link_pages` function works fine.
Also, when I redirect to *section-content.php*, I get the post title and linked pages looping with my else result of the post loop repeating in there as well. This confuses me because that means that it only fails when looking at the blog-content.php.
As for the looping, that's a seperate issue that I can figure out later, but the template is really confusing me.

Comment: You created section-blogcontent file. It was not php file. You should create  section-blogcontent.php

Comment: I don't know how i missed that. This has been bugging me for days and I didn't even check that.